# Xamarin.Forms MasterDetail Page catching the menu

Tags: xamarin.forms

I began to create a project, was following in the footsteps of this project "https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Hanselman.Forms" but when I begin to navigate the menu items get the following message:

`[Mono] [0xba013240] hill climbing, change max number of threads 4
[Mono] [0xba894098] hill climbing, change max number of threads 20`

and also realized that is catching the menu

Comment: You haven't actually asked us a question.

Answer (score 0):

Hill climbing is when the number of threads is increasing to help with throughput as it is under some heavy load.

All that is happening here is there is some intensive work going on in the background. You can just look at the code and debug to where it performing a lot of work and optimize those functions.

On Android I also find large images will cause this issue rather quickly. Reduce the size of images (it must be the size not the quality as that doesn't make any difference).